# Why doesn't my loop work when displaying data using jQuery but does in browser console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Issue Before:**

*When I run the loop using a console.log to display the data, it works. I get different headlines and it's corresponding snippets below. However when I include jQuery the headlines are repeated and the snippets do not display.*

**Updated Issue (includes thumbnail image and url links):**

I am using the NY TIMES API and I am trying to write a loop that will list article;

1. Headlines
2. Snippets
3. Thumbnail Image
4. NY TIMES Url's that they are linked to

I tried different variations of the loops written for the article Headlines and their Snippets to get article Thumbnail Images and NY TIMES Url's but I am not getting any luck, there are also no errors being thrown in the console.

Here is a JSFiddle including the JSON API data:

https://jsfiddle.net/m15xg45j/

Below is my JS for this.

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";

url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key' : "67dac4e994164fca920f7a8420e28dc2",
    'q' : "health"
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
}).done(function(result){

    var articles = result.response.docs;

    for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++){
      $("h2").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).html(articles[index].headline.main);
      });

      $("figcaption").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).html(articles[index].snippet);
      });

      $("img").each(function(index, el){
        $(el).html(articles[index].multimedia.url);
      });

      $("a").each(function(index, el){
        $("href").attr(articles[index].web_url)
      });
    }
}).fail(function(err){
    throw err;
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg01.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg01.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg02.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg02.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg03.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg03.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg04.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg04.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg05.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg05.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg06.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg06.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg07.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg07.jpg" alt="">
       <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg08.jpg">
    <h2>Headline</h2>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg08.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("h2").html(articles[i].headline.main);` will replace the contents of all currently existing `h2` elements with the contents of `articles[i].headline.main`. Same for the next line with the figcaption. If those elements don't exist yet, you won't get any output. I think you want to append the data to something, or create new elements, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @user3112619, you are overwriting the values every time. If you don't want to go the template method (you should consider it) - this will fix it for now -

```
var articles = result.response.docs;
$( "h2" ).each( function( index, el ) {
    $( el ).html(articles[index].headline.main);
});
$( "figcaption" ).each( function( index, el ) {
    $( el ).html(articles[index].snippet);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'm going to be posting another question regarding the corresponding thumbnail images and a CTA button.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the line:

```
$("h2").html(articles[i].headline.main);
```

Each time you loop through the for loop, that line sets the html of ALL H2 elements. So on the last iteration, all H2 elements have their html set to the last article.

You may want to consider:

```
var parent = $('.headline-collection');

for(var i=0; i<articles.length; i++) {
    var headline = $('<h2>' + articles[i].headline.main + '</h2>');
    parent.append(headline);
}
```

The html template inside that 'var headline...' line could be your entire article, and should probably be split into another 'factory' style method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the response of your get method. But can we try with $("someSelector").append("Sample Response"); ?